# Removing the network lock on a Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android

I am looking for a program that can remove the network lock on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (rooted Android 4.1.2 tied up to AT&T). It can run on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X or Android, free is better.

---

Network lock = I cannot use any SIM card other than the one provided by the [cell phone carrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators) (AT&T in my case) I got the phone from.

[image]